# Android: Using wakelock in service triggered by alarmmanager

Tags: java, android, service, alarmmanager, wakelock

In my application, I've got an alarm which triggers a service which downloads information from the internet and shows a notification.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

MyActivity contains this:

```
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 20);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmService.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 20000, pendingIntent);
```

And AlarmService looks like this:

```
public class AlarmService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        new myAsyncTask().execute();

    }

    private class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {

            //Download stuff

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void arg) {
            //Show notification
        }
    }
}
```

I don't really understand when to use wake-locks, so my question: in this case, should I use a wake-lock and if so, where should I start and stop it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will need to use a `WakeLock` to ensure that your service can finish its work.

If using an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) meets your design requirements, I would take a look at [WakefulIntentService](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful). It manages the alarms and the `WakeLock`s on your behalf and is easy to set up. The `WakeLock` is acquired when the alarm fires, and the `WakefulIntentService` library takes care of releasing it when the service is finished.

If you go this route, you won't want to use AsyncTask -- you'll need to keep the service actively busy (in its `doWakefulWork()` method) in order to hold the `WakeLock`.

Comment: Thanks, which file exactly should I download?

Comment: There's a .jar for the library available in the "Downloads" section of that GitHub link. The README has all the setup steps. You probably won't need the source to get started.